# DOM XSS: Find the function that sanitizes JSON responses

Tags: xss, rest, ajax, json, jquery

I am testing a web application where the HTML is built by JavaScript/jQuery/AJAX using the JSON respones from REST calls.

This being a very huge js file (require.js is also used), I'm finding it very hard to find the function which is sanitizing the JSON responses.   Backtracking from the AJAX call or from the functions listed in https://code.google.com/archive/p/domxsswiki/wikis/jQuery.wiki is taking me nowhere.

Is there any way I can track the execution of the JS step by step, before it creates the HTML source for me?
Any add-on which could help? I have tried the 'visual event' add-on from Chrome, but it is not completely helpful as it displays only the JavaScript function attached to an event for DOM elements.

Comment: in chrome developer tools you can add breakpoints on dom modification

Comment: This question doesn't fit into the scope of this network site. This is a post for StackOverflow.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://getfirebug.com/